# Troubles when formatting time on react coundown timer made with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Trying to make simple countdown timer with minutes and seconds to expire and reload button to reset it if need but I'm stuck with parsing the time in the right format. Here is live preview of what I did: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-poitras-t85mt?file=/src/App.js:0-654

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [countdown, setCountdown] = useState({
    expirityTime: 10,
    expired: false
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let time = countdown.expirityTime;
    if (time > 0) {
      const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        setCountdown({ expirityTime: time - 1 });
      }, 1000);
      return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="timer">Time Remaining: {countdown.expirityTime}</div>
      <button onClick={e => setCountdown({ expirityTime: 10 })}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Will be glad of any help. Tried `let time = countdown.expirityTime * 60;` to set the time from seconds to minutes first but the result is multiplied on every next setCountdown call. I'm really stucked.

Answer (score 0):

If you store all your state in seconds, i.e. 120s == 2 minutes, then you just need to do some simple math to compute minutes and seconds.

```
minutes = Math.floor(time / 60)
seconds = time % 60
```

So your render could be

```
<div className="timer">
  Time Remaining: {Math.floor(countdown.expirityTime / 60)}:
  {countdown.expirityTime % 60}
</div>
<button onClick={e => setCountdown({ expirityTime: 120 })}>Reset</button>
```

[image: Edit countdown time minutes:seconds]